# podsのライブラリでコンパイルエラー

Tags: ios, xcode6

お世話になります

podsのライブラリでコンパイルエラーになり、どうにも解決できず、抜け出せなくなってしまいました。

fmdb
smcalloutview

という二つのライブラリを（他にもありますが）使っているのですが、
以下のエラーで止まっております

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/Pods/build/Release-iphoneos'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/shiratsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-FMDB.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/shiratsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-FMDB.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/shiratsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-SMCalloutView.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/shiratsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-SMCalloutView.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/shiratsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/shiratsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FMDatabase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SqliteBaseService.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SMCalloutView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

ビルドアーキテクチャまわりかなと思って調べてるのですが、どうも違うようで、はまって抜け出せなくなってしまいました。
podファイルは以下です

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'KINWebBrowser'
pod 'SMCalloutView'
pod 'PonyDebugger' 
pod 'FMDB'
```

どなたかご教授願います

[image: PodsのBuildSetting]
[image: cafeのbuildsetting]

podのバージョンは

```
pod --version
```

`0.35.0`
でした

実はpodは今日アップデートしまして、そこからエラーが出ています
それまでは、問題なかったのですが、FMDBをcocoapodsで管理したく、元のプロジェクトにあるものを消して、cocoapodsから落としたところ、こういった状態になりました

cocoapodsのバージョンを下げました
そうするとエラーが変わって（多分前には進んだ）

```
 /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/NeoCafesagashi/SqliteBaseService.h:10:9: 'FMDatabase.h' file not found
```

FMDBはcocoapodsで入れたファイルです。見つからない理由ってなんでしょうか
Header Search Pathも正しくセットしたと思うのですが。。。
$(inherited)
/Applications/Xcode-Beta\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 試しにpodのバージョン0.35.0で新規のプロジェクトにpod installしたところ、問題なくビルドできるようです。既存のプロジェクトではなく新規プロジェクトでもエラーが出ますか？

Comment: 0.33.0で試しましたが、新規プロジェクトだとエラーが出なかったです。
これは、、、プロジェクトの何かが壊れてるということでしょうか

Comment: 新しいプロジェクトと比較しつつ、対応したら通りました！
ありがとうございます
回答は、別途書きます！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@h2so5さんのヒントを元に解決しました
多分cocoapodsのバージョン関係ないですね
まず、新しい別のプロジェクトにもとのPodfileをコピーしてインストールしました

```
    pod install
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.36.0.beta.2 is available.
To update use: gem install cocoapods\n
Downloading dependencies
Installing ARChromeActivity (1.0.2)
Installing FMDB (2.5)
Installing KINWebBrowser (1.1.0)
Installing PonyDebugger (0.4.0)
Installing SMCalloutView (2.0.3)
Installing SocketRocket (0.3.1-beta2)
Installing TUSafariActivity (1.0.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] From now on use `SampleDelegate.xcworkspace`.
```

でその後、ライブラリを読み込んでビルドしたところ、エラーが出ないので、
Build Settingsを確認したところ
Podで追加したものは、Header Search Pathsに

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/FMDB"

"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/"
```

などが追加されるのですが、されてなかったようです。ですので、手動で追加しました。
また、User-Definedに

```
PODS_ROOTを${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

にすれば、良かったみたいです
そこから、さらにもう一つエラーが出まして

```
Pods-resources.sh: No such file or directory
```

とでました
上記は
http://appstars.jp/archive/433
で解決しました
ありがとうございました